# Selecting from an arrray in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and want to be able to do a logical OR between different strings in two arrays, such that if user-inputA is equal to a string in array1 and if user-inputB is equal to a string in array2 it prints both strings.

There are 4 strings per array.

I have figured out how to do it by having just two variables rather than arrays, and using a bunch of if statments as follows:

```
var fname = prompt(), sname = prompt()
if (fname === "john" && sname === "doe")
{alert("Hello john doe")}
else if (fname === "dennis" && sname === "richie")
{alert("Hello dennis richie")}
else if (fname === "tim" && sname === "lee")
{alert("Hello tim lee")}
else if (fname === "bill" && sname === "gates")
{alert("Hello bill gates")}
else
{alert("name not found")}
```

But I would now like to use arrays rather than just having one sname and one fname. perhaps something like:

```
if ([0] in fname && [0] in sname) {alert(fname[0] + " " + sname[0])}
if ([1] in fname && [1] in sname) {alert(fname[1] + " " + sname[1])}
if ([2] in fname && [2] in sname) {alert(fname[2] + " " + sname[2])}
if ([3] in fname && [3] in sname) {alert(fname[3] + " " + sname[3])}
//each array has 4 strings
```

I'd like to keep this as minimal as possible (in terms of keywords and syntax I already know/will learn shortly) rather than somebody completley rewrite my code, though they probably would do it better.
Maybe theres just like one new keyword in order to do this?
I've heard of indexof() but cant tell if this is suitable.

Comment: What arrays? I don't see any arrays above.

Comment: I dont know how to add them in such a way that makes sense. but Ive included them sort of, but as pseudocode

Comment: I think it would help to show us example content of the arrays. I'm not sure if each array contains just forenames, or just surnames, or both?

Comment: one is forenames the other is surnames.

Comment: If you have an array, for instance `var a = ["doe", "richie", "lee", "gates"];`, you can check if a string is in that array via `a.indexOf(theString) != -1` or (on newer JavaScript engines) `a.includes(theString)`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array, for instance

```
var a = ["doe", "richie", "lee", "gates"];
```

...you can check if a string is in that array via `a.indexOf(theString) != -1` or (on newer JavaScript engines) `a.includes(theString)`.

So, changing as little as possible:

```js
var fnames = ["john", "dennis", "tim", "bill"];
var snames = ["doe", "richie", "lee", "gates"];
var fname = prompt(), sname = prompt();
if (fnames.indexOf(fname) != -1 && snames.indexOf(sname) != -1) {
    alert("Hello " + fname + " " + sname);
} else {
    alert("Name not found");
}
```

*(Or, again, we could use `if (fnames.includes(fname) && snames.includes(sname))`.)*

Of course, that will happily alert `"Hello tim richie"`.

If you want to check for matching pairs, then:

```js
var fnames = ["john", "dennis", "tim", "bill"];
var snames = ["doe", "richie", "lee", "gates"];
var fname = prompt(), sname = prompt();
var fnameIndex = fnames.indexOf(fname)
if (fnameIndex != -1 && snames.indexOf(sname) == fnameIndex) {
    alert("Hello " + fname + " " + sname);
} else {
    alert("Name not found");
}
```

That requires that the arrays be in the same order.

If you're doing pairs matching, though, it would be better to use a **single** array of objects and `Aray#some`:

```js
var names = [
  {fname: "john", sname: "doe"},
  {fname: "dennis", sname: "richie"},
  {fname: "tim", sname: "lee"},
  {fname: "bill", sname: "gates"}
];
var fname = prompt(), sname = prompt();
if (names.some(function(entry) {
    return entry.fname == fname && entry.sname == sname;
})) {
    alert("Hello " + fname + " " + sname);
} else {
    alert("Name not found");
}
```

...which looks a lot cleaner with ES2015's arrow functions:

```js
const names = [
  {fname: "john", sname: "doe"},
  {fname: "dennis", sname: "richie"},
  {fname: "tim", sname: "lee"},
  {fname: "bill", sname: "gates"}
];
const fname = prompt(), sname = prompt();
if (names.some(e => e.fname == fname && e.sname == sname)) {
    alert("Hello " + fname + " " + sname);
} else {
    alert("Name not found");
}
```

---

Side note: The man's name is Tim Berners-Lee, not Tim Lee. Only using part of a hyphenated name is as incorrect as using another name entirely. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var userInput = [prompt(),
  prompt()
];
var names = [
  ["john", "doe"],
  ["dennis", "richie"],
  ["tim", "lee"],
  ["bill", "gates"]
];

var print = names.find(function(e) {
  if (e[0] == userInput[0] && e[1] == userInput[1]) {
    return e;
  }
});

if (print != undefined) {
  alert("hello " + userInput[0] + " " + userInput[1]);
} else {
  alert("name not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing it, although I know you didn't want to rewrite your code completely.

```
let makeGreeting = (greeting, error) => {
  return (fname, sname) => {
    return fNames.includes(fname) && sNames.includes(sname)
      ? greeting + ' ' + fname + ' ' + sname
      : error;
  };
};

let sayHello = makeGreeting('Hello', 'Name not found');
sayHello('john', 'doe');
```